Get variable from identifier in a context
Is it possible in Python to get some abstract representation of a variable, given FrameInfo and location (line number and offset) of its identifier occurrence?
What I'd like to be able to do with it is change its value, find its definition site and all occurrences (which may form a proper subset of the occurrences of this identifier in the code associated with the frame), ideally also dynamically create a closure closing over it.
It's like what the ast module does, but enhanced with some rudimentary semantics. The interpreter already has to figure it out anyway, so maybe there's a way to get at it from within the programme.
Here's sample code that correctly identifies the call to f on the line f(), but on the next one it gives 2 as the position (f refers to a different function there) instead of 20:
from inspect import *
import io
from tokenize import *

def f():
    print('Doing something in function f.')
    detect()

def detect():
    name = stack()[1].function
    tokens = tokenize(io.BytesIO(stack()[2].code_context[0].encode()).read)
    for t in tokens:
        if t.type == token.NAME and t.string == name and all(c == next(tokens, None).string for c in '()'):
            print(f'Current invocation of function {name} was in line {t.line[:-1]} at position {t.start[1]}.')
            break

f()
([f() for f in ()], f())


Show us what you mean with example code, please. For changing its value, you may find setattr() helpful.

It's hard to write code using a feature about whose existence I'm asking. However, here parafoxia does almost this: https://gist.github.com/parafoxia/15ccda5db3e6805e93a4ef940ea27241. But his code just grabs the first token on the line that is the same identifier. It may mean something else at this occurrence, though. (Or be the wrong call if there are more than one, but that can be dealt with another way, keeping state.)

Please phrase your question more precisely, in terms of a unittest.TestCase. Show us a passing Green bar test for the aspect you already know how to implement, and a failing Red bar test for the aspect you’re asking about. // On pypi, look at how Beartype does dynamic type enforcement. It introspects annotations, similar I suspect to what you want to do.

That's a very high bar, I've never seen any similar request in other questions; I thought SO was meant to be supportive even for beginners. I'm not a beginner, but I don't know the unittest framework; if I learn it and the question will not have been answered, I may follow your suggestion. In the meantime I'm going to check beartype, it looks promising, thanks!

Program introspection is hardly a "beginner" problem.

By the time the script is running, there's no more syntax tree, it has been converted into byte code.

@Barmar, I meant it to suggest that questions should be judged according to equal standards, which should accommodate beginners too. As for the syntax tree and source code, that's what the inspect module is about. IIUC, it may raise an exception if the source code has been converted into byte code and not preserved. But that's not the case I'm asking about.

@J_H, although not using unittest.TestCase, I've edited the question to show code that approximates my goal and described how the behaviour I'd like to implement differs.
